# Ссылка с параметром телеграм бот

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Вроде как возможно вызвать команду с параметром https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking

Но у меня при запросе https://t.me/Name_bot?start=777 просто открывается окно бота и кнопка "Запустить".  Но после нажатия "Запустить" параметр никуда не передается.

```
    elseif (preg_match('~/start=\d+~m', $text, $match)) {
    $reply = $text;

    $telegram->sendMessage(['chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => $reply]);
}
```

Если просто написать боту эту команду, то параметр есть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но вот по внешней ссылке не могу его вызвать. Как быть?

Answer (score 1):

Все заработало!

Методом научного тыка установлено что нужно вызывать ссылку ?start=Тут ваш параметр

а в боте уже ловить ее как будто ничего не подошло

```
else {
    $telegram->sendMessage(['chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => $text]);
}
```

тогда будет кнопка "Запустить" и когда юзер нажмет ее - параметр отправится в чат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]